# Finite questions

Tags: scope

Are there a finite number of questions that can be asked regarding a specific language (and or topic), for example - for T-SQL given that there are only so many commands, can there be a limited number of non-repetitive questions? and if so can you use that to determine sizing for a site like stackoverflow and to determine the probability of a new question being a repeat of a prior one?  If there is a finite number, how would you determine/calculate it: for instance, T-SQL has x number of commands, each one can have a set of relevant questions (syntax, example of use, etc.) - so could the # of questions = x times potential questions time some relevant variation? or something like that?

Comment: And you could also calculate the total reputation that could be earned .

Comment: You need to include all APIs as well, not just all languages ... also techniques like OOP and TDD etc. are programming-related ... furthermore, this SBOK is perpetually increasing (e.g. we're seeing questions about Windows 7 now).

Comment: I meant "Software Body Of Knowledge": in the more general sense, i.e. all programming-related topics, i.e. the set of all questions that are relevent on this site (there's also a published http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWEBOK which isn't specifically what I meant).

Comment: Are there finitely many numbers or words?  Each comes from a finite set but they combination is what yields so many different possibilities, plus don't forget that technology will change and so new questions will arise around that so that what C# is now may not be the same language in a few years if new frameworks and IDEs become widely adopted.

Comment: "Are there finitely many numbers or words?" -- Yes if there's a maximum question length, otherwise maybe.

Comment: I heard that everyone on Stack Overflow either answers other people's questions or answers their own questions, except for the barber. He cuts people's hair. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stack overflow question is expressed as a finite length sequence of bytes.  One could in principle consider the question body in terms of an integer, expressed lowest digit first, in base 256 (or larger, if you wish to think about it as unicode).  This is a bijection between questions and whole numbers.  Therefore the set of all stack overflow questions has a countably infinite cardinality (How do i typeset \aleph_0 in SO?).

Comment: But not every conceivable question, as you define it, can be understood or belongs on Stackoverflow. You have not yet proven that the set of questions that is appropriate for this site is also countably infinite.

Answer (score 4):

No, since, theoretically, programs can be of infinite length, and this site is not just about language commands, but programs developed with those languages.

Comment: In theory they could be, but in reality there's some limitation - either way the length of the program is not a direct reflection of the size of the command set - the commands and patterns will repeat throughout the code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure Turing says no, and if you don't believe him them Gödel might have something to say about it.

Comment: And Bertrand Russel too, if you're going to ask questions about questions.

Comment: Gödel  spoke of completeness - which would probably hold that no language or theory can be proved complete (I think that's how it relates) - but does not mean that the language is not finite.